# Python NameError: not defined

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to create an accumulating total based on users input.

```
class Accumulator:
    # Create self value == 0
    def __init__(self, newval = 0):
        self.value = newval

    # Addition function
    def add(self, newval):
        return self.value + newval
```

Then I have several different functions that go here. After the functions are all complete I set my operator equal to anything other that 'T' which instantly terminates the program. Here when i try: newval, operator is where I get my first error, secondly I will get the error "add" is not defined.

```
operator = 'z'

while operator != 't' or operator != 'T':
    try:
        newval, operator
    except:
        #Prompt user to enter a number and valid operator
        newval, operator = input("Enter a valid number, space, then an operator: ").split()
```

Below here, depending on what the users inputs for the operator calls whatever function associated with the letter. Take "A" for example:

```
elif operator == 'a' or operator == 'A':
        print(add(self, newval))
        self.value = add(self, newval)
```

Then My program should keep the accumulating total and continue running... untill the user enters 't' or 'T'.

Comment: just a quick comment: `operator` is the name of one of python's module. so maybe not good idea to use this name as variable.

Comment: I agree with @Marcin, please avoid using python module name for variable.

Comment: Ok I will. I didn't realize operator was a module.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `self.add` if you are using inside class

```
elif operator == 'a' or operator == 'A':
    print(self.add(self, newval))
    self.value = self.add(self, newval)
```

If you are not using inside same class then you have to use object varibale

```
a = Accumulator()
...
...
elif operator == 'a' or operator == 'A':
    print(a.add(self, newval))
    self.value = a.add(self, newval)
```

Comment: Still tells me: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Python Files/test5.py", line 52, in <module>
    self, operator
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: can I send you an email so you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have tried both ways and still can't get it working.

Comment: If you can update question with full code then also I can help.

Comment: I finally got it. Thanks tho @Lafada I appreciate the help

Comment: If you can add your solution, it will help others too.